# How do i scrape this? can't get the elemens out in beautifoul soup, I do see them in HTML

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

can't get any info :( I would need everything in the container ID but it shows up empty

running anaconda python 3.7 and total noob

when i do a div i get nothing eventhough there are plenty.. I think it's related to this piece of html code,  how can i do this best?

if I take the html frame code I get this

```
<script type="text/javascript">var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();(function(){var 
s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")
```

[0];s1.async=true;s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5e7dc7ff69e9320caabd918a/default';s1.charset='UTF- 
   8';s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);})();

but if i inspect i get all details! cant even screencopy the code?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://horecacomeback.be/nl/zaak/?companyid=1761324' 
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#also tried html here nothing :(
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")    
print(soup.body)

<body>
   <div class="s-browser__msg17" id="s-browser__msg" style="display:none">
      <div class="s-content">
         <div class="s-icon">
            <svg height="24" preserveaspectratio="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <circle cx="12" cy="21.3" r="2.7"></circle>
               <path d="M12,0c-1.5,0-2.7,1.2-2.7,2.7v10.7c0,1.5,1.2,2.7,2.7,2.7s2.7-1.2,2.7-2.7V2.7C14.7,1.2,13.5,0,12,0z"></path>
            </svg>
         </div>
         <div class="s-title">Browser not supported</div>
         <div class="s-text">Unfortunately, you are using an outdated browser. Please upgrade to a more current version or try a different browser. Supported browsers are: Chrome, Firefox, Edge &amp; Safari.</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <header class="s-nav__banner4" id="s-nav__banner4">
      <div class="s-flex__wrapper">
         <a class="s-logo__link" href="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" target="_self"><img alt="[:swvar:ufile:5:description:]" class="s-logo" src="/swfiles/files/logo.svg?nc=1588663531"/></a> 
         <nav class="s-nav"> <a class="s-page" href="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" target="_self">Steun een zaak</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/registreer-uw-zaak/" target="_self">Registreer uw zaak</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/faq/" target="_self">FAQ</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/partner-worden/" target="_self">Partner worden</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/visuals/" target="_self">Download visuals</a></nav>
         <div class="s-wrapper">
            <div class="s-lang__switcher">
               <div class="s-lang--active s-page--sub"></div>
               <div class="s-lang__list"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="s-cta__btn" href="https://wwc.resengo.com/login?lang=NL&amp;frame=1&amp;theme=business&amp;relocate=pq%2FFsL5gXV3FwLxirI%2BhvZuhwV2JnpdSc4qyxJuMkJOfmI9zi4A%3D" target="_blank">Aanmelden</a>
         </div>
         <button class="s-overlay__trigger"><span class="s-trigger__span"></span><span class="s-trigger__span"></span></button>
      </div>
   </header>
   <div class="s-nav__overlay4" id="s-nav__overlay4">
      <a class="s-logo__link" href="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" target="_self"><img alt="[:swvar:ufile:6:description:]" class="s-logo" src="/swfiles/files/logo-white.svg?nc=1588663531"/></a> 
      <nav class="s-nav"> <a class="s-page" href="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" target="_self">Steun een zaak</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/registreer-uw-zaak/" target="_self">Registreer uw zaak</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/faq/" target="_self">FAQ</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/partner-worden/" target="_self">Partner worden</a><a class="s-page" href="/nl/visuals/" target="_self">Download visuals</a></nav>
      <a class="s-cta__btn" href="https://wwc.resengo.com/login?lang=NL&amp;frame=1&amp;theme=business&amp;relocate=pq%2FFsL5gXV3FwLxirI%2BhvZuhwV2JnpdSc4qyxJuMkJOfmI9zi4A%3D" target="_blank">Aanmelden</a> <button class="s-overlay__trigger"><span class="s-trigger__span"></span><span class="s-trigger__span"></span></button>
   </div>
   <main id="sw_content">
      <div class="s-comp21" id="scomp77">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="s-content"><img alt="" class="s-logo" src="/swfiles/files/logo-white.svg?nc=1587558230" title=""/></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="s-comp18" id="scomp44">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="s-wrapper">
               <a class="s-overview__link" href="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" target="_self">
                  <svg height="34" preserveaspectratio="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path d="M12,0L9.9,2.1l8.4,8.4H0v3h18.3l-8.4,8.4L12,24l12-12L12,0z"></path>
                  </svg>
                  Overzicht
               </a>
               <div class="s-company" data-hcb-btn="Kopen" data-hcb-company="" data-hcb-overview="/nl/steun-een-zaak/" data-hcb-title="Waardebonnen" data-hcb-url="/nl/waardebon/"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </main>
   <div class="s-social__banner7" id="s-social__banner7">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="s-content">
            <div class="s-social__list"> <a class="s-social fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/horecacomeback" target="_blank"></a> <a class="s-social fa fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/horecacomeback" target="_blank"></a></div>
            <div class="s-legal__list"> <a class="s-link" href="https://www.resengo.com/Code/Legal/?DocumentID=16437&amp;DocumentUID={9EF91481-7512-402F-8B65-E21F789997C8}&amp;DocumentTypeID=2&amp;LC=NL" target="_blank">privacy</a> <a class="s-link" href="https://www.resengo.com/Code/Legal/?DocumentID=16437&amp;DocumentUID={9EF91481-7512-402F-8B65-E21F789997C8}&amp;DocumentTypeID=2&amp;LC=NL" target="_blank">cookies</a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <link href="/swfiles/body/20200422142350.page.1.6.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script src="/swfiles/body/20200422142350.lay.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();(function(){var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s1.async=true;s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5e7dc7ff69e9320caabd918a/default';s1.charset='UTF-8';s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);})();</script><script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5e8ae588ae3a32a0" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/swfiles/body/20200422142350.page.1.6.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `to scrap` = putting it into the trash

Comment: that data is dynamically rendered. need to use something like Selenium to let the page render first.